# Why can't 3-SAT be solved efficiently if you convert all clauses (x ∨ y ∨ z) into (u ∨ z) by introducing a variable?

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, boolean-algebra, 3-sat, 2-sat

Let $a_i$, $b_i$, etc., be a literal, i.e., a variable or the negation of a variable.

3-SAT concerns formulas in CNF form: $(a_1 \vee a_2 \vee a_3) \wedge \dots \wedge (b_1 \vee b_2 \vee b_3)$ (3-CNF).  The problem of whether or not such a formula has an assignment of its Boolean variables such that it evaluates to $1$ is NP-complete.

But if we can convert the 3-CNF formula into a 2-CNF efficiently, then using implication graphs, we know that 2-SAT is in the complexity class P, which would make 3-SAT lives there as well.

So I'm wondering what are the obstacles to doing this?

For example, why can't we do this to remedy it (working with a clause at a time):

$$F := (a \vee b \vee c) \\
u := (a \vee b) \\
\text{But, this assignment (equality) is true} \iff \\
G := (u \vee \bar{a}) \wedge (u \vee \bar{b}) \wedge (\bar{u} \vee a) \wedge (\bar{u} \vee b) =1. \\
\text{ So, } F = 1 \iff \exists u~(u\vee c) \wedge G = 1.
$$

And all we've done is swapped out one 3-CNF clause in favor of 5 2-CNF clauses.

I'm not seeing why this wouldn't make 3-SAT polynomial time.

Comment: While this approach does not work (as explained by John L) to reduce 3-SAT to 2-SAT, something very similar does indeed work to reduce even longer clauses longer down to 3-SAT. This means that 3-SAT is equivalent to general SAT, which allows any size of clause.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> $u = (a \vee b) \iff 
> (u \vee \bar{a}) \wedge (u \vee \bar{b}) \wedge (\bar{u} \vee a) \wedge (\bar{u} \vee b) =1 $

Unfortunately, the equivalence above does not hold.

Let $a=\text{false}$, $b=\text{true}$, $u=\text{true}$.

- the LHS is $\text{true}$.
- the RHS is $\text{false}$ since $\bar u\lor a=\text{false}\lor\text{false}=\text{false}$.

---

In fact, we can prove the following.
**Claim**: there is no 2-CNF formula $\varphi(a,b,c,x_1,\cdots,x_m)$ such that $\forall a, b, c\in\{\text{false, true}\}$,
$$a\lor b\lor c \iff \exists x_1 \cdots \exists x_m ~\varphi(a,b,c,x_1,\ldots,x_m).$$

Comment: For the proof of the claim, use the fact that majority on three inputs is a polymorphism of width-2 clauses but not of width-3 clauses.